# How to send 'get' parameter to 'source' callback in jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery

I'm tring to add a get parameter to the source callback like so :

```
 source: "/getvalues?myparam="+$('#myId).val
```

But when I inspect using the 'Network' tab on Chrome what is actually to server its :

```
getvalues?myparam=&term=a
```

$('#myId).val does contain the character 'a' but I dont know how/why the '&term=' is being generated? How can I send a 'get' parameter as part of the source callback ?

Comment: term is the variable that jQuery gives to access the current value in the auto complete..a query string is added with a term field, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#myId').val() //p00f! [that should do it ^_^]
```

Comment: thanks, do you know where I can find a good tutorial on autocomplete? http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ oesnt seem to goin this kind of detai

Comment: @user701254 it says ['Check out the API Documentation'](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). Learn to read :-P

Comment: I take offence to that comment, if you dont want to answer my question thats fine but if you do, that does'nt give an excuse to insult.

Comment: @user701254 the `:-P` was to show that it was no offense intended. You obviously have not been using the internet for long ^_^